Terraform on GCP: Internal error 500 when reading or editing app engine application
We are deploying a project on GCP using terraform with our desired project-id. However I first created the project manually and now I want to have it specified in terraform. As we were through the development we re-deployed the project multiple times using our existing terraform infra.
So I try to import the project to the terraform state:
Import
terraform import module.application-airport.module.engine.google_app_engine_application.app projects/desired-project-id/locations/europe-west1/applications/desired-project-id

As the application cannot be deleted, we tried to disable and re-enable it multiple times hoping for a miracle.
With debug logs on we currently see:
2024-05-29T16:47:04.261+0200 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.80.0_x5: -----------------------------------------------------
2024-05-29T16:47:04.261+0200 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.80.0_x5: 2024/05/29 16:47:04 [DEBUG] Dismissed an error as retryable based on error code: googleapi: got HTTP response code 500 with body: HTTP/2.0 500 Internal Server Error
2024-05-29T16:47:04.261+0200 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.80.0_x5: Alt-Svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000
2024-05-29T16:47:04.261+0200 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.80.0_x5: Cache-Control: private
2024-05-29T16:47:04.261+0200 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.80.0_x5: Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
2024-05-29T16:47:04.261+0200 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.80.0_x5: Date: Wed, 29 May 2024 14:47:04 GMT
2024-05-29T16:47:04.261+0200 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.80.0_x5: Server: ESF
2024-05-29T16:47:04.261+0200 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.80.0_x5: Vary: Origin
2024-05-29T16:47:04.261+0200 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.80.0_x5: Vary: X-Origin
2024-05-29T16:47:04.261+0200 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.80.0_x5: Vary: Referer
2024-05-29T16:47:04.261+0200 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.80.0_x5: X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
2024-05-29T16:47:04.261+0200 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.80.0_x5: X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
2024-05-29T16:47:04.261+0200 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.80.0_x5: X-Xss-Protection: 0
2024-05-29T16:47:04.261+0200 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.80.0_x5
2024-05-29T16:47:04.261+0200 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.80.0_x5: {
2024-05-29T16:47:04.261+0200 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.80.0_x5:   "error": {
2024-05-29T16:47:04.261+0200 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.80.0_x5:     "code": 500,
2024-05-29T16:47:04.261+0200 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.80.0_x5:     "message": "Internal error encountered.",
2024-05-29T16:47:04.261+0200 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.80.0_x5:     "errors": [
2024-05-29T16:47:04.261+0200 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.80.0_x5:       {
2024-05-29T16:47:04.261+0200 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.80.0_x5:         "message": "Internal error encountered.",
2024-05-29T16:47:04.261+0200 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.80.0_x5:         "domain": "global",
2024-05-29T16:47:04.261+0200 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.80.0_x5:         "reason": "backendError"
2024-05-29T16:47:04.261+0200 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.80.0_x5:       }
2024-05-29T16:47:04.261+0200 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.80.0_x5:     ],
2024-05-29T16:47:04.261+0200 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.80.0_x5:     "status": "INTERNAL"
2024-05-29T16:47:04.261+0200 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.80.0_x5:   }
2024-05-29T16:47:04.261+0200 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.80.0_x5: }
2024-05-29T16:47:04.261+0200 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.80.0_x5: 2024/05/29 16:47:04 [DEBUG] Dismissed an error as retryable. Retryable error code 500 - googleapi: got HTTP response code 500 with body: HTTP/2.0 500 Internal Server Error
2024-05-29T16:47:04.261+0200 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.80.0_x5: Alt-Svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000
2024-05-29T16:47:04.261+0200 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.80.0_x5: Cache-Control: private
2024-05-29T16:47:04.261+0200 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.80.0_x5: Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
2024-05-29T16:47:04.261+0200 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.80.0_x5: Date: Wed, 29 May 2024 14:47:04 GMT
2024-05-29T16:47:04.261+0200 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.80.0_x5: Server: ESF
2024-05-29T16:47:04.261+0200 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.80.0_x5: Vary: Origin
2024-05-29T16:47:04.261+0200 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.80.0_x5: Vary: X-Origin
2024-05-29T16:47:04.261+0200 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.80.0_x5: Vary: Referer
2024-05-29T16:47:04.261+0200 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.80.0_x5: X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
2024-05-29T16:47:04.261+0200 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.80.0_x5: X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
2024-05-29T16:47:04.261+0200 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.80.0_x5: X-Xss-Protection: 0
2024-05-29T16:47:04.261+0200 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.80.0_x5
2024-05-29T16:47:04.261+0200 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.80.0_x5: {
2024-05-29T16:47:04.261+0200 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.80.0_x5:   "error": {
2024-05-29T16:47:04.261+0200 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.80.0_x5:     "code": 500,
2024-05-29T16:47:04.261+0200 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.80.0_x5:     "message": "Internal error encountered.",
2024-05-29T16:47:04.261+0200 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.80.0_x5:     "errors": [
2024-05-29T16:47:04.261+0200 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.80.0_x5:       {
2024-05-29T16:47:04.261+0200 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.80.0_x5:         "message": "Internal error encountered.",
2024-05-29T16:47:04.261+0200 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.80.0_x5:         "domain": "global",
2024-05-29T16:47:04.261+0200 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.80.0_x5:         "reason": "backendError"
2024-05-29T16:47:04.261+0200 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.80.0_x5:       }
2024-05-29T16:47:04.261+0200 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.80.0_x5:     ],
2024-05-29T16:47:04.261+0200 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.80.0_x5:     "status": "INTERNAL"
2024-05-29T16:47:04.261+0200 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.80.0_x5:   }
2024-05-29T16:47:04.261+0200 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.80.0_x5: }
2024-05-29T16:47:04.261+0200 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.80.0_x5: 2024/05/29 16:47:04 [DEBUG] Retry Transport: Waiting 1m12s before trying request again
2024-05-29T16:47:07.890+0200 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.80.0_x5: 2024/05/29 16:47:07 [DEBUG] Retry Transport: Stopping retries, context done: context deadline exceeded
2024-05-29T16:47:07.890+0200 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.80.0_x5: 2024/05/29 16:47:07 [DEBUG] Retry Transport: Returning after 11 attempts
2024-05-29T16:47:07.891+0200 [ERROR] provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.80.0_x5: Response contains error diagnostic: tf_rpc=ReadResource diagnostic_severity=ERROR tf_proto_version=5.3 tf_req_id=68e98ddf-051c-a392-21f4-05b7ab3c795e tf_resource_type=google_app_engine_application @caller=github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-go@v0.14.3/tfprotov5/internal/diag/diagnostics.go:55 @module=sdk.proto diagnostic_detail="" diagnostic_summary="Error when reading or editing App Engine Application \"projects/desired-project-id/locations/europe-west1/applications/desired-project-id\": googleapi: Error 500: Internal error encountered., backendError" tf_provider_addr=registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google timestamp="2024-05-29T16:47:07.891+0200"
2024-05-29T16:47:07.893+0200 [ERROR] vertex "import module.application-airport.module.engine.google_app_engine_application.app result" error: Error when reading or editing App Engine Application "projects/desired-project-id/locations/europe-west1/applications/desired-project-id": googleapi: Error 500: Internal error encountered., backendError
2024-05-29T16:47:07.893+0200 [ERROR] vertex "module.application-airport.module.engine.google_app_engine_application.app (import id \"projects/desired-project-id/locations/europe-west1/applications/desired-project-id\")" error: Error when reading or editing App Engine Application "projects/desired-project-id/locations/europe-west1/applications/desired-project-id": googleapi: Error 500: Internal error encountered., backendError
2024-05-29T16:47:07.893+0200 [ERROR] vertex "module.application-airport.module.engine.google_app_engine_application.app (expand)" error: Error when reading or editing App Engine Application "projects/desired-project-id/locations/europe-west1/applications/desired-project-id": googleapi: Error 500: Internal error encountered., backendError
╷
│ Error: Error when reading or editing App Engine Application "projects/desired-project-id/locations/europe-west1/applications/desired-project-id": googleapi: Error 500: Internal error encountered., backendError
│
│
╵

2024-05-29T16:47:08.093+0200 [DEBUG] provider.stdio: received EOF, stopping recv loop: err="rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = error reading from server: EOF"
2024-05-29T16:47:08.094+0200 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.80.0_x5: 2024/05/29 16:47:08 [DEBUG] [transport] [server-transport 0x14001641860] Closing: Server.Stop called
2024-05-29T16:47:08.094+0200 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.80.0_x5: 2024/05/29 16:47:08 [DEBUG] [transport] [server-transport 0x14001641860] loopyWriter exiting with error: transport closed by client
2024-05-29T16:47:08.094+0200 [DEBUG] provider.stdio: received EOF, stopping recv loop: err="rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = error reading from server: EOF"
2024-05-29T16:47:08.094+0200 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google-beta_v5.31.1_x5: 2024/05/29 16:47:08 [DEBUG] [transport] [server-transport 0x14000499380] Closing: Server.Stop called
2024-05-29T16:47:08.094+0200 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google-beta_v5.31.1_x5: 2024/05/29 16:47:08 [DEBUG] [transport] [server-transport 0x14000499380] loopyWriter exiting with error: transport closed by client
2024-05-29T16:47:08.100+0200 [DEBUG] provider: plugin process exited: path=.terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google/4.80.0/darwin_arm64/terraform-provider-google_v4.80.0_x5 pid=5922
2024-05-29T16:47:08.100+0200 [DEBUG] provider: plugin exited
2024-05-29T16:47:08.100+0200 [DEBUG] provider: plugin process exited: path=.terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google-beta/5.31.1/darwin_arm64/terraform-provider-google-beta_v5.31.1_x5 pid=5924
2024-05-29T16:47:08.100+0200 [DEBUG] provider: plugin exited


Currently I am at the point of trying to deploy everything automatically using a different less desirable project id :(

I think I was hitting the same issue but when I looked again at the Terraform docs I noticed that you should only specify the project ID for the application you are trying to import. So in your case the command should be:
terraform import module.application-airport.module.engine.google_app_engine_application.app desired-project-id

